# Android smack.util.StringUtil does not have parseBareAddress

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, instant-messaging

I was looking for different ways to support offline messaging in my application but each of these examples include parseBareAdress and Android studio gives error stating that it cannot resolve parseBareAdress. It can resolve everything else. Here is my code

```
import org.jivesoftware.smack.util.StringUtils;

public static void handleOfflineMessages(XMPPConnection connection, Context ctx)throws Exception {
        OfflineMessageManager offlineMessageManager = new OfflineMessageManager(connection);

        if (!offlineMessageManager.supportsFlexibleRetrieval()) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Offline messages not supported");
            return;
        }

        if (offlineMessageManager.getMessageCount() == 0) {
            Log.d(TAG,"No offline messages found on server");
        } else {
            List<Message> msgs = offlineMessageManager.getMessages();
            for (Message msg : msgs) {
                String fullJid = msg.getFrom();
                String bareJid = StringUtils.parseBareAddress(fullJid);
                String messageBody = msg.getBody();
                if (messageBody != null) {
                    Log.d(TAG,"Retrieved offline message from " +messageBody);
                }
            }
            offlineMessageManager.deleteMessages();
        }
    }
```

Here are my dependencies

```
  compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android-extensions:4.1.0-alpha6'
    compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.1.0-alpha6'
```

Comment: I have been looking for the same answer.

Comment: That is a problem but you can split the adress with hand. I have a bigger problem, I cant get the offline messages can you?

Comment: Yes, I am able to. Ping me on individual conversation if you have any specific query, I might be able to help out.

Comment: I can not start an individual conversation with my current reputation. Can you provide the snippet which succeeds in recieving offline messages?

Comment: It is more to do with the settings of your Server. Go to Server Settings and check what you have set for "Offline Messages". If you choose "Store" and then if you choose under "Client Connections" an idle time beyond which a user is disconnected, you will be able to receive offline messages.

Comment: Does that mean this code is correct and the failure is reasoned because of the server? Because I am not the one who writes the back-end side hence I need to contact with him to provide me that value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131445/discussion-between-krishnan-v-s-and-prethia).

Answer (score 0):

Replace `StringUtils.parseBareAddress(fullJid)` with this custom method:

```
/**
 * Input: user@server/Smack || user@server-035<br>
 * user<br>
 * @param jid
 * @return bareAddress
 */
public static String parseBareAddress(String jid)
{
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(.+)(@.+)");


      Matcher matcher = regex.matcher( jid );
      if (matcher.matches())
      {
          return matcher.group(1);
      }

      return jid; //safe condition
}
```